# Gradle defaultConfig vs buildtypes.all vs buildtypes.each

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have search Gradle official website and Android Developer official website, but could not find an answer to this.

1. In the Andoroid build.gradle, what is the difference between defaultConfig, buildtypes.all, and buildtypes.each. They all seems to have a same effect that set build configuration for different build types (release, debug, etc.)
2. Why might I use one over the other?

   ```
   android {
       ...

       defaultConfig {
           ...
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               ...
           }
       }
       buildTypes.all {
           ...
       }
       buildTypes.each {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is this more related to Groovy script?

Comment: Maybe see "Configure Product Flavors" section [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors)

Comment: Product flavors and buildTypes are used for different purposes. buildTypes are for configuring different build states (debug, release, etc.) where as flavors are different version of releases (free, paid, Kit Kat compatible, Lolipop compatible, etc.)